# Performance of fur garments?

Tags: clothing

1. How does the performance of genuine fur garments, as might have been used traditionally, compare to that of down and modern synthetics?  (Insulating power (wet and dry), water repellency, and any other quantifiable comparisons.)
2. What types of furs were used historically, by whom, and for what applications?  What furs are still used today?

Ideally I would like to see actual data and sources for the comparisons, not merely inferences and anecdotes.

Comment: Many furs are still in use today by cats, bears, wolves, musk oxen, etc. Some of these are regularly exposed to cold and wind and the population is still there, so they musk work pretty well.

Comment: Also be aware that what you might buy today as a fur garment is also not made the same, at the very least, the cut is likely different than in previous times.

Comment: @Olin Yes, which is part of the motivation for my question.  Nevertheless people and animals are different; sea otters eat about one third of their body weight *every day* so for example a human in a complete suit of sea otter fur is still not going to survive icy water.

Comment: @sdg I'm not particularly interested in fur garments available today, but rather the comparison between historical and modern.  I guess a secondary interest would be the use of animal pelts in a survival situation but that's fanciful.

Comment: A big difference between fur and down/synthetic/synthetic fur is that fur has a leather backing, usually adding considerable weight.

Comment: I really think this should be two questions. The first question will have a decent sized answer, and the second question is two questions and either will draw a rather long list. (Not to mention this S.E. could really use more questions/day.)

Comment: @MaskedPlant I'll consider splitting this soon.

Answer (score 6):

A little research led from a Finnish [blog](http://bushcraftfinland.atfreeforum.com/clothing-f48/comparison-between-modern-and-traditional-inuit-clothing-t348.html) to the source **[article](http://www.int-res.com/articles/cr/5/c005p083.pdf)**, which appears to have been published in the journal **Climate Research** in 1995.  There is another posting comparing [early](http://bushcraftfinland.atfreeforum.com/clothing-f48/comparison-between-modern-and-early-20th-century-clothing-t347.html) 20th century *modern* clothing, to that of *today*, i.e. 2012.

In the 1995 study, they found that for a sedentary individual, such as a passenger on a sled, the traditional caribou and other fur clothing were indeed superior to the *modern* clothing

> The laboratory data support the recommendations of Unit elders to use caribou skin clothing for long-term protection for sedentary individuals exposed to a cold winter climate.

It goes on, however

> it is not necessarily better for active users

as this study was looking at stationary people, without the effect of sweat upon the insulative qualities of the garments.

N.B. marked this answer as wiki, as it only starts to answer the several specific questions of the posting.